# Sbt alternative to "mvn install -DskipTests"

Tags: scala, maven-2, sbt

I'm trying to instal sbt based project to local maven repository. I have tried commands:

- `"sbt publish"` - require repository credentials
- `"sbt publish-local"` install to .ivy repositry, but I need maven!

How can I do such operation in terms of SBT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The SBT wiki](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Publishing.html#Define+the+repository) has the goods.  Just define the repo (look for "Publishing to the users local maven repository" on the linked page) and invoke "publish".

Answer (score 5):

Using SBT 0.13 and without editing the project source files:

- Create (or edit) a `global.sbt` file in `~/.sbt/0.13`:

  `vim ~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt`
- Add the following line:

  `publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file",  new File(Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository")))`
- Save and close the file
- Run `sbt publish` from the project folder

Comment: "Error running deliver: java.lang.RuntimeException: Repository to publish to not specified."